# Proof of $f(x)=\sin x +x$ is Surjective

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Without plotting graph prove that $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x)=\sin x+x$$ is an Onto function

Let $y_0$ be any number in codomain Then we require atleast one $x_0$ in Domain such that $y_0=\sin x_0 +x_0$

Now since $\sin x_0$ is bounded in $\left[-1 \:\: 1\right]$  we have

$$x_0=y_0-\sin x_0$$

hence there is an $x_0$ in Domain. So $f$ is surjective. But i feel something missing in this proof? Any other way to prove?

Comment: How do you know such an $x_0$ exists? That's the part you're missing. Essentially: for any number $a$, does $sin(x)+x-a=0$ have a root?

Comment: For all $n$, $\sin (n\pi)=0$ , so $f(n\pi)=n\pi$. Now you can use intermediate value theorem to conclude (using continuity)

Comment: use the Intermediate value thm.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is an odd function so it suffices to prove surjectivity onto $[0,\infty).$ Note that $f$ is everywhere continuous, that $f(0)=0$ and that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty.$

Now, if $y\in \mathbb R^+$, since$f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ there is an $x\in R^+$ such that $f(x)> y$, so we can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to get an $0\le c\le x$ such that $f(c)=y$.